# Get time from datetime in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a CSV file with following syntax

```
7   11/11/2010 10.59.54 marty86ce   2.499
8   11/11/2010 10.59.57 marty86ce   2.533
9   11/11/2010 11.00.00 marty86ce   2.516
10  11/11/2010 11.00.03 marty86ce   2.508
```

I have to plot on the 5h column on the vertical axis (RTT in milliseconds from a network experiment) and the time, even approximate, of the measure on the horizontal axis.

I noticed that pasting the graph I produced so far into Word, and resizing it to make it smaller, shows only the date.

I would like to get the hour only from the second column to plot into the graph.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1)+1,FIND(".",B1)-FIND(" ",B1)-1)
```

This uses the space after the date and the period after the hour to isolate that hour number.